# Identify and select row if entry appears for first time in column based on criteria? (SQL)

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, subquery, where-clause

I am using VBA and ADODB.Connection to extract data from an Access database. I would like to select data from the database if an entry in a specific column appears for the first time. This is best explained by example so here is a sample table I quickly made in Excel, let's pretend the table is called "DrinkTable"

[image: Sample table made in Excel]

I would like to extract transactions that took place after 9/1/2020 by a **new name** (it was the first time that name ever purchased a drink, there name never appears in the name column before 9/1/2020).

I am able to write an SQL statement that pulls all the entries after 9/1/2020 using: `"SELECT [Name], [Drink], [Cost], [Date] FROM [DrinkTable] WHERE [Date] >= #"9/1/2020#" ORDER BY [ID] DESC;` but that does not give what I am attempting. The correct output I am looking for is:

[Sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7Qqc.png)

Can someone help me refine my SQL statement to only extract data if the entry in the [Name] column did not appear before "9/1/2020?"

Comment: Ahh good catch! Sorry I made this quickly and missed adding him - updated the post now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `not exists` to filter out rows whose `Name` appeared before the split date:

```
SELECT [Name], [Drink], [Cost], [Date] 
FROM [DrinkTable] d 
WHERE 
    [Date] >= #"9/1/2020#" 
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [DrinkTable] d1
        WERE d1.[Date] < #"9/1/2020#" AND d1.[Name] = d.[Name]
    )
ORDER BY [ID] DESC
```

Comment: Struggling to get this to work with ADOBD in VBA but will keep you updated

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT d1.[Name], [Drink], [Cost], [Date] FROM [DrinkTable] AS d1
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT [Name] FROM [DrinkTable] WHERE [Date] < #9/1/2020# ) as d2
ON d1.name = d2.name
WHERE ISNULL(d2.name)
```

Comment: Trying this out, will keep you posted